# How to publish android library to Jfrog bintray?

Tags: android, maven, bintray

I am working on Android library development, i have already finished my library work and generated aar and jar file, but when i am trying to publish to binary at that time i am getting one error message.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mylittlelibrary:bintrayUpload'.
> Could not create package 'abcd/maven/helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary': HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [message:Repo 'maven' was not found]

* Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.391 secs
Could not create package 'abcd/maven/helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary': HTTP/1.1 404 Not    Found [message:Repo 'maven' was not found]
2:41:59 AM: External task execution finished 'bintrayUpload'.
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
}

 group = 'helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary'
 version = '1.0.2'

 task generateSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
     from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
     classifier 'sources'
 }

 task generateJavaDocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
     classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath()
        .join(File.pathSeparator))
 }

 task generateJavaDocsJar(type: Jar) {
     from generateJavaDocs.destinationDir
     classifier 'javadoc'
 }
 generateJavaDocsJar.dependsOn generateJavaDocs

bintray {
    user = 'abcd'
    key = '1234567890fghgfhffjfgjfjfjrtyjtkjg'
    pkg {
       repo = 'maven'
       name = 'helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary'

    version {
        name = '1.0.2'
        desc = 'My test upload'
        released  = new Date()
        vcsTag = '1.0.2'
    }

    licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
    vcsUrl = ''
    websiteUrl = ''
}
configurations = ['archives']
}

artifacts {
   archives generateJavaDocsJar
   archives generateSourcesJar
}
```

[image]

Please kindly go through my script and suggest me some solution.

Comment: Do you have a repo named maven under your account?

Comment: hey thanks issue solved...i created a name under my maven account

Comment: @DeeptimanPattnaik - i can only create organisation in my account and then create a repo. I did that and it din't help me. Any help?

Comment: Step by step instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43951025

Answer (score 2):

Before you publish to Bintray you must have a stable build of your code.
The hierarchy on Bintray is the following:
User --> Repo --> package --> version --> artifact
means that the Repo should be above the package by that hierarchy.

The following lines in your gradle.build are probably the main cause for the error:

```
pkg {
    repo = 'maven'
    name = 'helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary'
}
```

The hierarchy is wrong.

When using maven you should check that you comply with the maven convention, else the Maven Build can not succeed. [Explanation for Maven Repositories on Bintray.](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/formats/formats_mavenrepositories.html)

The error you had:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [message:Repo 'maven' was not found]
```

Means that you do not have a Repository on Bintray calls maven. All the packages versions and files should be under the Bintray Repository you have created.

For more details or support issues you can use the [Bintray support](https://www.jfrog.com/support-service/support/) team which is available for all Bintray users and can help you with any problem related to any JFrog platform services such as Bintray, Artifactory, Mission control & Xray.

Answer (score 0):

```
pkg {
    repo = 'maven'
    name = 'helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary'

    version {
        name = '1.0.2'
        desc = 'My test upload'
        released  = new Date()
        vcsTag = '1.0.2'
    }

Could not create package 'abcd/maven/helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary': HTTP/1.1 404 Not    Found [message:Repo 'maven' was not found]
2:41:59 AM: External task execution finished 'bintrayUpload'.
```

**'abcd/maven/helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary'**

- abcd : bintray user name
- maven : pkg { repo = 'maven' } set by you, example 'abcd/android-lib/helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary' when set repo = 'android-lib'
- helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary : pkg{ name = 'helloaar.example.com.mylittlelibrary'

-

- first : check your bintray account,
- second : make repository,
- third : modify your pkg repo = 'input making repository name from second step' build.gradle
- last : build again

i hope help for you, have a nice day