# How to update library for new version in Bintray?

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter

[image]

I published my library to jCenter as v1.0.0 by using `novoda/bintray-release` at the first time.
Actually I want to update it as v1.0.1, how can i do it?

[EDITED] I added the image for release note of another library as below.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to change the version in the publish section of your build.gradle file. Then, run the plugin again.

This will create a new version in bintray.

Comment: yeap I tried to update it after I changed `publishVersion` but it made new one.

Comment: There is no functionality for renaming versions in Bintray. You can delete the old one.

Answer (score 9):

These are the steps I follow whenever I update my Bintray library:

1. Update the `libraryVersion` name in your library module build.gradle file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43951025/3681880) for more on that.

   ```
   ext {
       ...     
       libraryVersion = '2.0.0'
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Create a new version in [Bintray](https://bintray.com/login) that matches what you called `libraryVersion` in your build.gradle file.

[image]

3. In the root folder of your project, run the following command in a terminal.

   ```
   ./gradlew bintrayUpload
   ```

   There are different things that can fail here. Google the error code to solve it. Here were a couple recent ones for me.

   - [JavaDoc generation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45748516/3681880)
   - [Could not sign version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750333/android-studio-gradle-bintray-upload-failed-could-not-sign-version)
   - [Dex error On Android Studio 3.0 Beta4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053902/dex-error-on-android-studio-3-0-beta4)
4. Update your [GitHub](https://github.com/) documentation and [create new release](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) matching the Bintray version.

After following these steps my project was immediately updated on Bintray (and jCenter).

#### Notes

- It is possible to make an update by only changing the `libraryVersion` and running `./gradlew bintrayUpload` (and not create a new release in Github or a new version in Bintray). However, when I did that it removed the version history in Bintray, so my current preference is to do all four steps above.

#### Related

- [How to distribute Android library in jCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43951025/3681880)