# Dex error On Android Studio 3.0 Beta4

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dex

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult;
```

Comment: show `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya This is not a duplicate of the reported question. At least for me, the problem started with AS 3.0 beta 4 and I already use multidex.

Comment: How? I don't have privileges, I think

Comment: @ADev Yes . Thanks for mention . Its a bug ? sure ?

Comment: I don't know yet for sure. But I can run `./gradlew assembleRelease` on the command line without problems.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya still not sure if it's a bug but I posted an answer with the solution I found to the problem.

Comment: Not working in Android Studio 3.0 RC2

Comment: Try and add this to your gradle file:
_multiDexEnabled true_  **It worked for me.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android MultiDex: an all time salvation is imperative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104198/android-multidex-an-all-time-salvation-is-imperative) (I know it is newer, but it is way better than this error-text-only post!)

Answer (score 56):

I have same problem with Android Studio 3.0 beta 4. I found a solution.

**1.** From the `Build` menu, press the `Clean Project` button.

[image: Clean Project]

**2.** After task completed, press the `Rebuild Project` button from the `Build` menu.

[image]

Comment: I'm happy to help part of solution of your problem

Comment: I wonder, why is the answer not usefull and why report 
 the answer? @SagarTrehan

Comment: This works on Android Studio 3.1 Canary.  However it seems like i have to do this each time i make changes to gradle.  Is there a lot term fix for this?

Comment: Worked for me using Android Studio 3.0

Answer (score 28):

For Android Studio 3.0 what I did was to add this to my gradle:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

And it worked!

Example

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true //Add this
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for me, this does not resolve the problem... I still continue working on resolve it..

Comment: Try these steps: Delete your .gradle, clean and rebuild. Also don't forget add multiDexEnabled. Hope it helps

Comment: If you enable multidex and your minSDK is less than 5.0, then follow the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 19):

So I solved this issue by doing the following:

- Delete the `./gradle` folder inside your project
- Delete all the **build folders and the gradle cache**. I ran the following command:

How ?

```
 cd ~/[your project root folder] && find . -name build -exec rm -rf {} \; && rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

Assuming your **gradle config files** are in the `$HOME/.gradle` folder.

- Inside Android Studio, went to `File > Invalidate caches / Restart...` and invalidated the caches and restarted it.

Comment: Delete .gradle folder fixes my problem. Thanks for help!

Comment: Same issue on AS 3.0 Beta 7, unfortunately this is still not working for my case.

Comment: Have tried all above solution but does not work for AS 3.0 beta 7. Kindly help

Comment: I still have the problem in AS 3.0.1

Comment: Invalidate caches and restart have broken all my Android Studio settings...

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to get to the cause of this error by inspecting your dependencies with gradle and looking for duplicates like this:
**`./gradlew -q app:dependencies`**

In my case, the following error was happening at build time:

```
Duplicate zip entry [httpcore-4.4.1.jar
```

and it was resolved by doing this in my `build.gradle`:

```
implementation ('me.dlkanth:stetho-volley:1.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

Comment: In my case 'com.android.volley' was being added twice somehow,  I also added the exclude statement, now  its working fine.

Comment: running this script gave me `could not determine java version from 9.0.1`.  I updated to Gradle from 4.1 to 4.2.1 using Android Studio 3.0

Answer (score 7):

**If your minSdkVersion is 21 or higher**

```
   android {
        defaultConfig {
           multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
```

**if your minSdkVersion is 20 or lower**

**1)** you must add the following library in dependencies

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**2)** Create a java class then extend it from Application and override attachBaseContext method.

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

**3)** Mention the created class inside manifest in application tag.

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
.
.
.
    </application>
```

Comment: If above code does not work then check your every library in the gradle by holding cursor on it, if it has available new version then Update it, sync, clean project, rebuild project and run. hopefully, it will work for you.

Comment: This code works for Android 5.1 and above... for below android version.. there is another way to add multidex support. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 6):

Check your dependencies for latest version usually it is inconsistency with the version of any of your dependencies.

1.Build > Clean Project 
2. Rebuild your project

Check the verbose log for the dependency causing the merge issue and update the same. Repeat the same for each dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

I faced same issue in Android Studio 3.0.1, I tried all possible cases nothing worked for me as mentioned above, finally I solved it by

**Solution1:**

- Close Android Studio
- Delete `.gradle` folder located at `C:\Users\YourComputerName\.gradle` **not from app's `.gradle`**
- Restart android studio

It will download all the necessary jars and add to your build path

**Solution2:**

- Delete duplicate jar from libs folder in app/libs
- Rerun the app again

Because if there is duplicate jar file which already defined in `build.gradle` file it causes issue.

This solved the issue for me. It may help others..

Comment: what about a Linux User ? Same error I am getting. Please guide me

Comment: Do the same thing which I mentioned in your linux. i.e., Go to terminal the location of .gradle would be something like '~\.gradle\'

Comment: I am trying but its not visible..  Which location you are trying to explain ? Where I installed my Android studio or project location  ?

Comment: No it is in your user home i.e., for ex: `~/.gradle/caches/..`

Comment: Thank you ... I solved it. There was mismatch version code

Comment: Glad to helped you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160257/discussion-between-shylendra-madda-and-nihal-softy).

Answer (score 1):

This error can have multiple reasons.
No clean and rebuild or anythging like that did the job for me.

For me the problem was the dependency:

```
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
```

I removed it and everything worked fine.

Comment: How did you get this conclusion? By trial and error?

Answer (score 1):

Change "compile" to "compileOnly"
this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the culprit was SendGrid lib, added this and it got fixed:

```
compile 'com.github.danysantiago:sendgrid-android:1',{
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Studio 3.0.0 release. In my case there was the only solution: I have removed old JARs from the "libs" folder in my project: it was "ksoap2" package with dependencies. Packages obtained with gradle usually do not conflict with each other, at least if you are using the most popular ones. But an old JAR in libs folder may crush your build if it includes all own dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried other comments from removing gradle and bla bla bla, but adding `multiDexEnabled true`  solving my problem, I investigate that my apk has reached Over 64K Method.

[image]

> Ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am using 
Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017

I delete jar file from libs folder. And that work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 and was facing the same problem. If others answer doesn't works try this:

Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

It worked for me [Sync Project with Gradle Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPk13.png)

Answer (score -1):

Sometime it can happens due to same library (jar file) present two times or your project has reached 64k methods limit.

Solution: 
1) Remove Databinding if your project use this
2) Remove same type library from lib folder or, delete .gradle file from c//user//your_pc//.gradle
3) apply this in your build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```