# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex exception on run time

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDevDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion project.buildToolVersion
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }


    productFlavors {

        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://raconfiguratorqa.symx.com"'
            resValue 'string', 'google_maps_key', "AIzaSyDqXirXTahZHrKeSW62kmY3236S1Cqu4c4"

        }

        production {

            buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"https://raconfiguratorqa.symx.com"'
            resValue 'string', 'google_maps_key', "AIzaSyDqXirXTahZHrKeSW62kmY3236S1Cqu4c4"

        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'contsynckey'
            keyPassword 'techjinikd'
            storeFile file('../KeyStore/contsynckey.jks')
            storePassword 'techjinikd'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kdcos.contsync"
        minSdkVersion project.minSDKVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.targetSDKVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        flavorDimensions "versionCode" // This we had to put for Android Studio 3.0
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$project.firebaseVersion"
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$project.espressoCoreVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    //support libraries
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$project.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$project.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$project.constraintLayoutVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$project.supportLibraryVersion"



    // for generateQrCode 3.2.1

    compile "com.google.zxing:core:$project.qrCodeVersion"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

bildgradle for application

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.0'
    ext.android_plugin_version='3.0.0-alpha5'
    ext.couchbase_version='1.4.1'
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        google()

        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}


project.ext {

    supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.2'
    buildToolVersion = '26.0.2'
    playServicesVersion = '11.6.2'
    firebaseVersion = '11.6.2'
    retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
    compileSDKVersion = 26
    targetSDKVersion = 26
    minSDKVersion = 18
    gsonVersion=2.7
    rxAndroidVersion='2.0.1'
    rxJavaVersion='2.0.2'
    constraintLayoutVersion='1.0.2'
    junitVersion='4.12'
    espressoCoreVersion='2.2.2'
    lifecycleVersion='1.0.0-rc1'
    ottoVersion='1.3.8'
    daggerVersion='2.12'
    glideVersion = '4.2.0'
    archRoomVersion = "1.0.0"
    loggingVersion='3.8.0'
    qrCodeVersion='3.2.1'
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

please look my build.gradle file i am always getting after clean and build on run time given exception and even i have restart android studio and restart android system and reopen then try to run app then also  i am getting same exception please suggest me what i am doing wrong .

Comment: Hopefully, there is a Java stack trace in the Gradle Console that will show exactly what is going wrong. If there is, and you do not understand what it says, edit your question and post that entire stack trace.

Comment: Post complete log trace

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDevDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 17s  this erros is coming gradleconsole

Comment: this is coming logcat  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDevDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android MultiDex: an all time salvation is imperative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104198/android-multidex-an-all-time-salvation-is-imperative)

Answer (score -1):

When I get this error I do the following.

1. Uninstall the version from my phone/emulator and re-install it
2. If that doesn't work, it is usually a problem the gradle dependencies. You may have inconsistent versions e.g `play-services:11.6.2 and firebase:11.6.1` *(These are just examples)*. Check your build.gradle file if there are warnings

Comment: Play service version is not reached to 27.0.2. Mentioned problem will not be solved through uninstall app.

Comment: Wow, I thought I edited the play services bit. I mean 11.6.2

Comment: Have you done a clean build and rebuild of your project under the `build` tab in Android Studio

Comment: yes i have clean restart all the thing i did but i dont know where is problem

Comment: yes  i have restart clean all the thing i did but i dont know where is issue coming @martinomburajr