# Add compile 'com.google.android.gms: play-services-ads: 11.6.0' ERROR

Tags: debugging, service, compilation, playback

I Add Google Play Services ADS

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms: play-services-ads: 11.6.0
```

ERROR, I did as a guide: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

> `Error:Execution failed for task:HDWallpapresApp:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkD9W.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4FAR.png]

Please help me, thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android MultiDex: an all time salvation is imperative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104198/android-multidex-an-all-time-salvation-is-imperative)

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException` yields [this page](https://github.com/wonderkiln/CameraKit-Android/issues/218) which seems to indicate your problem is a mismatch of versions on your dependencies.

I can't see the rest of your gradle file since you posted it as an image rather than text, but have a look at the dependencies section in the bottom to see if there are any conflicts.

Ultimately, you should read all the info on the [Android Multidex Salvation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46104198/1739000) question/answer and follow its troubleshooting steps before posting a new question.