# Why android studio 3, show me this error?

Tags: java, android

somebody can tell me, why Android Studio 3.0.1, show me this error when make app?

```
Execution failed for task ':joy-android-game-gdx:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

The next attach *my build gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.websmithing.gpstracker"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 15
            versionName "4.0.5"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
        compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

    }
```

the app compila when i delete this line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
```

but the app after moment automatic close

Comment: What is happening if you uncomment multiDexEnabled true?

Comment: hi, with o without multiDexEnabled show me same error

Comment: First, follow the troubleshooting steps at [Android MultiDex: an all time salvation is imperative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104198/android-multidex-an-all-time-salvation-is-imperative) (of which this post is most likely a duplicate)

Comment: the app compila whe delete this line: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0', but the app after moment close

Comment: Try adding this line to your dependencies: `com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0` . It might not compile because `play-services:9.8.0` refers `mediarouter-v7:24.0.0` so you are not compiling the same version for all the `com.android.support` dependencies group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.websmithing.gpstracker"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 15
            versionName "4.0.5"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
        compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    }
```

Beside this, please review your dependency versions. They are not the latest versions and you might want to update them. Take care of the buildToolsVersion as well.