# Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, telegram

I get this problem when I use source code of Telegram in Android studio. So I use android studio preview 3.0.0 beta 2, gradle 4.1-all.zip, mainsdk:15.
I did everything but it's not working properly.

Error is :

> Error:Execution failed for task:
>   TMessagesProj:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:  com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

**`build.gradle`** file is :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.5.+'
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("config/debug.keystore")
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        foss {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    sourceSets.debug {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    sourceSets.release {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    sourceSets.foss {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/foss/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.telegram.plus"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 458
        versionName "2.5.2.1"

    }
}
```

so `gradle-wrapper.properties` is 
`services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

Comment: It seems that you use the old version. Have you try the newest one at https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dex error On Android Studio 3.0 Beta4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053902/dex-error-on-android-studio-3-0-beta4)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'
```

If that works. Replace it with the specific parts of play-services you need, e.g:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0'
```

for Google Cloud Messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below it worked for me

- Delete the ./gradle folder inside your project
- Delete all the build folders and the gradle cache. I ran the following command:

based off 
[Dex error On Android Studio 3.0 Beta4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053902/dex-error-on-android-studio-3-0-beta4)