# Fail demo:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForMockDebug with a DexArchiveMergerException

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

After a rebuild I get :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':demo:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForMockDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzag
```

What does that error message mean? What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I replaces gradle `implementation`  instruction by (the older) `compile` , it works.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118739/errorexecution-failed-for-task) for this error is to delete the `./gradle` folder inside your project or delete all the **build folders and the gradle cache**.

Additional references:

- [Dex error On Android Studio 3.0 Beta4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053902/dex-error-on-android-studio-3-0-beta4)
- [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

> 1. Delete the `.gradle` directory.
> 2. Run your app again.
>
> **Notes**
>
> - The `.gradle` directory is in your project's root folder. (You may have to show hidden files first.)
> - I have to do this every time I update a dependency module using Android 3.0.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This error (and any other `Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.xxxxxx` error) can be caused by different Play Services and Firebase versions. Make sure *all* `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:xxxx:12.0.0` and all `implementation 'com.google.firebase:xxxxxx:12.0.0'` have the same version (12.0.0) in this example.