# RunTime exception: DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex in android studio 3

Tags: java, android, dex

I am building a project which is using java lamda expressions and so i recently switched to android studio 3. 
My project is successfully building but generating runtime exception as follows:-

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Project level build.gradle:-

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-rc2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir 
}
```

app level build.gradle:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled  true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

implementation project(":app:libs:myfolder")
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Output of gradlew --stacktrace : https://ghostbin.com/paste/3kebt

I have tried clean and rebuild method, and other methods mentioned in other stackoverflow answers to similar question. But nothing works.

Edit: Already mentioned that none of the method of  [Dex error On Android Studio 3.0 Beta4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053902/dex-error-on-android-studio-3-0-beta4) is working in my case and so it is not the same case and this is not the duplicate question.

Thus I need help in resolving this issue. 
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @Mark: Duplicate of which question

Comment: @SagarTrehan Look at the top, block "This question already has an answer here:"

Comment: @Mark: Yes I saw the answer. But none of the answers working in Android Studio rc2. What should I do now?

Comment: @Ronaldo7: Did you get it working?

Comment: @SagarTrehan Then I suggest you look at the "Linked" question section of that duplicate, and if none of those work, post a new question, clearly explaining **how** none of those solve your problem.

Comment: @Mark: Posted new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933926/android-studio-3-0-rc2-runtimeexception-dexarchivemergerexception-unable-to-m

Comment: No guys, None of the solution from other answers are working.