# I m Using volleyplus and volley libraries in Signal android project

Tags: java, android, network-programming, android-volley, android-library

```
 android {
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "testing.gps_service"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
            }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
    }

  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

  compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
  compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'

  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
  }
  repositories 
  {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
  }
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
  -------------------------------------------------------
  ## I'm new to Android, currently working on FYP, as I run my project, an  
   error is occurred.##
```

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976279/dexarchivemergerexception-unable-to-merge-dex)

Comment: I'm trying your suggested solution but it did not work :(

Comment: Is it possible to use two libraries com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0 and
  dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus in single Project?

Comment: Oooh I am sorry may be try the other suggested way in the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Compile with

```
compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'
```

hope that will help

Comment: I tried this one also didn't work, error remains same.

Comment: Is it possible to use two libraries com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0 and dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus in single Project?

Comment: first off all why are you trying to import both of them ?

Comment: Actually I'm a student, new to Android. I worked on Volley 1.0.0 earlier and then I needed to send image to server so I saw a solution for sending image (multipart data) in Volleyplus, so I used Volleyplus.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Link for Upload Image "https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/"

Comment: You might want to better specify how this helps solving that specific problem.