# Multi desk error when I integrate linked In library to in my android project

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am getting error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I added linked in sdk successfully but when I compile project(':linkedin-sdk') then give me error i tried to resolve this error i also try multiDexEnabled true but still get error this is my app.gradle file

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

        }

    }

    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://developers.quikkly.io/nexus/repository/maven-releases/' }
        maven { url 'http://developers.quikkly.io/nexus/repository/maven-snapshots/' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
        compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
        compile 'com.brucetoo.pickview:library:1.2.3'
        compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1'
        compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'

        // Pretty color picker
        compile('com.thebluealliance:spectrum:0.7.1') {
            // spectrum uses older support libs, override these with latest.
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        }
        compile('net.quikkly.android:quikklycore-lib:1.2.0@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        compile 'net.quikkly.android:quikkly-lib:1.2.0@aar'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        // Include all the Twitter APIs
        compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
        // (Optional) Monetize using mopub
        compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'

    }
```

this is my linkedin gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

buildscript {
   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
   }

}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
          setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 17 
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16 
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
    }
}

configurations {
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
}
```

I  used android studio 3.0 RC 2 with cannery  if any kind of help or suggestion please let me know thank in advances 

EDIT:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Comment: you mind posting your error ?

Comment: did you go through his https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053902/dex-error-on-android-studio-3-0-beta4 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: @Jatin You need to add the error in your post not in the comment

Comment: @Lokesh i refer this side but not get any kind of solution

Comment: did you try clean and rebuild ?

Comment: @Lokesh i rebuild and clean the code and also try with invalid Cashes /Restart but still get same error

Comment: I suggest that you edit the question and post the entire output of your Gradle console. Your specific problem (e.g., duplicate class definition) should be reported elsewhere in that output. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46978913/115145).

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your linkedin gradle file:

```
allprojects
{
    repositories
    {
        maven
        {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

public class ApplicationClass extends MultiDexApplication {
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Comment: @JatinDevani did you check my given link ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i check link and i also implement that way but still get same error

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i just copy and paste that class from link that are given by you

Comment: @Jatin Devani Have you try the MultiDexApplication?

Comment: @AmjadKhan i try with MultiDexApplication but still get same error

Answer (score 0):

I am putting up the complete MultidexApplication code

app gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

Or if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the `attachBaseContext()` method and call `MultiDex.install(this)` to enable multidex:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

> **Caution:** Do not execute MultiDex.install() or any other code through reflection or JNI before MultiDex.install() is complete. Multidex tracing will not follow those calls, causing ClassNotFoundException or verify errors due to a bad class partition between DEX files.