# How to fix transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug in Android

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

In my application I want use     `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'` 
but when running application show me this error in **Logcat :**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I added **`multiDexSupport`** with this code but not work me and again show me this error!

**Codes for multiDex:**

```
//Build.gradle
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tellfa.colony"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 12
    versionName "22"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
}

// MultiDex
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

//Application class
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

How can I fix it? please help me

Comment: Look in the Gradle Console output for more details, usually in the form of a stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am amateur. can you help me more? please

Comment: You will find the Gradle Console docked at the bottom of the Android Studio window. Open it. Read the contents. Look for a Java stack trace. If you do not understand it, edit your question and past in the stack trace (or the entire Gradle Console output).

Comment: @CommonsWare, hey my friend in Console just show me above error! just show above error

Comment: I feel very confident that there is more in the Gradle Console than just those lines. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46982823/115145) for a stack trace that Gradle might log to the Gradle Console.

Comment: @CommonsWare, hey my friend I know what is stack trace. but just show me this **2lines :** `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex`

Comment: My guess is that you are looking at the Messages tool, not the Gradle Console tool. Regardless, without the stack trace from Gradle, I cannot help you further.